# Suspicious "push" directory in Android phone storage

Tags: file-management

**Android version: 5.0**
**Directory:** `push > locks > [files]`

There's more than 3000 files in that `locks` directory. Each file has a name similar to `55ee5f08..._1471113497966` in length 38 characters. Each file has *no* file extension, and is zero bytes in size. The entire `locks` directory is zero bytes in size as well.

**What is the purpose of this directory? Can I safely delete it?**

Comment: Is it a Mi phone? Also what is the complete path of directory? Is your phone rooted?

Comment: @beeshyams Thank you for helping! My phone is Micromax Unite 3. It is NOT rooted. The complete path is `phone > push > locks > [files]`

Comment: Sorry no idea about that